# About `npm install -g` cannot add to environment variables

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

English is not my mother tongue, I will try my best to describe the problem.

I use nvm for windows to manage my node. And my node version is 18.17.0.

When I use `npm install -g pnpm`, actually it install pnpm. But it didn't add pnpm to windows' environment variables.

How to fix the problem? Let the node can add environment variables with `npm install -g`.

Comment: try using instance of cmd for using `pnpm`

Comment: I use `pnpm` in cmd. But it say ：'pnpm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

If `npm install -g pnpm` successfully installs pnpm, but it doesn't add pnpm to Windows' environment variables, you can follow these steps to manually add it to your PATH:

1. Find the pnpm installation directory:
   First, you need to locate the directory where pnpm is installed. By default, npm global packages are installed in the `node_modules` directory within the npm installation path.

   For nvm, the global npm packages are usually stored in a path like:

   ```
   C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\<node_version>\node_modules
   ```
2. Add pnpm to the PATH environment variable:
   Once you find the pnpm installation directory, you can add it to the PATH environment variable.

   - Right-click on "This PC" (or "My Computer") on your desktop and select "Properties".
   - In the System Properties window, click on "Advanced system settings".
   - In the System Properties dialog, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
   - In the Environment Variables dialog, find the "Path" variable under "System variables" or "User variables" (choose the appropriate one based on your preference). Click "Edit".
   - Click "New" and add the path to the pnpm installation directory. For example, it could be something like:

     ```
     C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\<node_version>\node_modules\.bin
     ```

     Make sure to replace `<your_username>` with your actual username and `<node_version>` with the specific version you are using.
   - Click "OK" on all open windows to save the changes.
3. Verify the installation:
   Open a new command prompt or PowerShell window and run `pnpm -v` to check if pnpm is now recognized and accessible from any directory. You should see the version number of pnpm printed in the console.

Please note that you might need to restart any open command prompt or PowerShell windows for the changes to take effect. After following these steps, pnpm should be available globally and accessible from any directory on your system.

An other approach could be using the following command from https://pnpm.io/installation#on-windows in the PowerShell

```
iwr https://get.pnpm.io/install.ps1 -useb | iex
```

I hope this helps, otherwise let me know.